# Accessing elements in an array of hashes of hashes (Perl)

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I have populated the array `@a` with hashes of hashes, so that:

```
$a[0]{'keyA'}{'keyB'}
```

Gives me a value.

I would now like to select an element in the array (say index `0`) and loop through all the elements in the hash in alphabetical order like so:

```
for my $keyA (sort keys $a[0]) {
    for my $keyB (sort keys $a[0]{$keyA}) {
        print $a[0]{$keyA}{$keyB};
    }
}
```

Im not sure why but Perl completely skips the loop. I can see this when stepping through using the Eclipse debugger.

A data::dump of my array:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {},
          {
            'Z' => { 'Z' => 1 },
            'G' => { ''  => 1 },
          },
          undef,
          {
            'A' => { 'A03' => 1, 'A02' => 1 },
            'G' => { 'G29' => 3 },
            'Z' => { 'Z' => 1 },
            'F' => { 'F24' => 2, 'F27' => 1 },
          },
          {
            'A' => { 'A02' => 2 },
            'O' => { 'O62' => 1 },
            'B' => { 'B05' => 1 },
          },
        ];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should never, ever say things like "Perl doesn't seem to like..". You should copy/paste the error(s).

Comment: What is the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@a;`? This would show us the data structure you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The array contains references to hashes. You need to dereference them:

```
for my $keyA (sort keys %{ $a[0] })
   for my $keyB (sort keys %{ $a[0]{$keyA} }) {
```

More info on references can be found in [`man perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Exactly what unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Did you dereference the inner loop also?

Comment: No error is given it seems to skip the loop completely. I can see this when I run it using the Eclipse debugger. i.e. the interpreter never enters the loop

Comment: Looking at the dump added to your question, `$a[0]` is a reference to an empty hash

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works. This is my code that works on a dummy array.
I guess your problem is that you didn't test whether your array element is actually hash ref of a hash ref. For example, if `$a[2]` is `'foo'`, then your code breaks. If this is the case, you then have to test each element and each hash value of an element. For example, `if (ref $array[0] eq 'HASH'){...}`

```
my @array = ({'a'=>{'aa'=>11, 'bb'=>12, 'cc'=>13},
              'b'=>{'aaa'=>21 , 'bbb'=>22, 'ddd'=>23},
              'c'=>{'aaaa'=>31, 'bbbb'=>32 , 'cccc'=>33},
            });

for my $keyA (sort keys $array[0]) {
    for my $keyB (sort keys $array[0]{$keyA}) {
        print $array[0]{$keyA}{$keyB},"\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

Comment: It dosn't work for my code. Maybe its the way I initialize the array. I use: @a = ({}); and then populate it by going through a loop and entering each element separately, like: $a[0]{'a'}{'aa'} = 68;

Comment: @Josh perhaps you don't need array if `@a` has only one element?

Comment: The array will have more than one element in the end